# AJAX External URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am developing a simple Mobile App that displays currency rates from an XML file. Now, the problem is that I read the XML from my server so I have to put the full URL in .ajax but it dosen't seem to work with external URLs. Can someone tell me how can I fix this or how to replace the code so it will work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/currencies.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {



    $(xml).find('Currency').each(function(){

    var Name = $(this).find('Name').text();
    var ValueUSD = $(this).find('ValueUSD').text();
    var ValueEUR = $(this).find('ValueEUR').text();
    var ExValueUSD = $(this).find('ExValueUSD').text();
    var ExValueEUR = $(this).find('ExValueEUR').text();

    $('#content').append('<div class="currencyBox"><div class="currency">'+Name+'</div><div class="tab1"><div class="half">'+ValueUSD+'</div><div class="half">'+ValueEUR+'</div></div><div class="tab2"><div class="half">'+ExValueUSD+'</div><div class="half">'+ExValueEUR+'</div></div></div>');

    });



    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You will never be able to do an ajax request to a different domain. You will have to write some server-side script you can call and let that script retrieve the remote file.

Comment: If you are loading your HTML from the file:// protocol than web browsers on iOS, Android and BB will not be affected by the same origin policy. PhoneGap apps often take advantage of this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at jquery doc about jsonp. There is possibility to do cross site request in html5 especially, however most tools (firebug, noscript, adblock) and some browsers on default are bloking such requests. So I would stick to jsonp as most reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Doesnot work with Cross-Domain due to same origin policy. Try JSONP in such case.